Does an interaction mean anything if there is no main effect?
I ran a psychology experiment where I manipulated the participant's task. While I'm looking at the effect of Task on my measure, I also wanted to explore whether there is a trial order effect on that measure.
I've plotted the data (averaged by trial order) and it looks like this:

I fitted a mixed effects linear model DV ~ Task*Trial + (1+Task | subject) to the data (sum-coded Task and numeric Trial), which gave me a significant main effect of Task (such that Task 1 was significantly different from the grand mean) and an interaction between Task and Trial (such that the effect of Trial was different in Task 1 than the grand mean). There was no main effect of Trial.
I then fitted models like DV ~ Trial + (1 | subject) to the data from each Task. However Trial was not a significant predictor of data in any Task, although the magnitude was different for Task 1, where Trial was a positive predictor, and the other two, where Trial was a negative predictor.
Now I wonder how I should interpret the interaction between Task and Trial in the big model. Does it matter in any way? Can I say in my discussion that the effect of Trial was different in Task 1 than in the other two, even though Trial was not a significant predictor in any of the smaller models?
Thanks for any input!

Your small models suffer from omitted variable bias and I would not report the results of those. In the full model It doesn’t matter if either of the main effects are “not significant”. You should retain the main effects,  and try not to worry about  p-values and “significance” based on some arbitrary cut-off point of their values.

In general it is very well possible to have a interaction effect without main effects. If some effect is +a for one group and -a for another group, and those groups are of equal size, then you get that the average effect is zero. Non-significant main effects while the interaction is significant, just means that the average effect is smaller than individual grouped effects, in such an extent that the average effect is not significant different from zero. There are probably several questions about this already.

Your example is difficult to analyse because it is not very clear what 'subject' is and it doesn't appear in the presentation of your data. Did you measure repeatedly the same subject with different trials and or tasks?

So, I'll add another comment that might be useful for some.  If the main goal of your analysis is simply to obtain the best predictions of outcomes, and you have no interest in interpreting your model coefficients, then absolutely, you can include interactions without the main effects, so long as your interactions only model has better predictive performance compared to your model that includes them.  This might be the case in some analytical scenarios.  However, if you do intend to have an interpretable model you'll want to include the main effects.

Also see Including the interaction but not the main effects in a model

An interaction means the effect of one predictor on the response depends on the value of another predictor.  So when the AB interaction is significant, I don't think it makes sense to interpret the main effects of A or B, because each of their effects depends on the other.  Instead of interpreting the main effects, I just try to make sense out of the interaction.  For me, this usually involves looking at a graph of the interaction, doing comparisons of the means among of each combination of AB, and doing tests of simple effects (meaning holding on factor constant while doing ANOVA on the other factor).
The Analysis Factor believes that there are times it does make sense to interpret main effects when there is an interaction: https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/interpret-main-effects-interaction/

(+1) Visualization goes a long way to dispelling what main and interaction effects mean. In my answer here, I show how plots from interaction models simply represent adjusted intercepts and slopes, so that the "main effects" are just the baseline group's intercept and slope, whereas the other coefficients are the changes in lines for the comparison group. There is no "main" regression line / effect anymore when this happens.

I agree with all of the comments and @Tarek.Elnaccash's answer about the importance of including the both main effects and the interaction in the same model. The main effect of the variables involved in an interaction are the means for those variables when the other variable it is interacting with is equal to 0. Accordingly, it is a good idea to code those variables such that 0 a meaningful value. Otherwise it can be difficult to interpret the main effect coefficients.
Specifically related to testing the main effect of Trial, one option is to run a post-estimation Wald test for the categories. The car package's linearHypothesis() should be able to handle this for you.
m1 <- lmer(DV ~ Task*Trial + (1+Task | subject), data=dat)
car::linearHypothesis(m1, c("Trial=0"))

